# Error in closing embeded Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am doing a web application, which is planned to allow a client website to embed javascript from my web application in the following way on its page called TEST:

```
<script src="http://example.org/showPopup.js"></script>
```

Suppose my web application is at http://example.org.

I am able to dynamically load jQuery and Fancybox and open a Fancybox iFrame popup window via showPopup.js when the TEST page is loaded. Here is showPopup.js:

```
(function () {
    var requestedJQuery = false;
    var requestedFancyBoxJs = false;
    var requestedFancyBoxCss = false;

    function requestJQuery() {
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        myScript.async = false;
        myScript.src = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body' [0])).appendChild(myScript);
        requestedJQuery = true;
    }

    function requestFancyboxJs() {
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        myScript.async = false;
        myScript.src = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body' [0])).appendChild(myScript);
        requestedFancyBoxJs = true;
    }

    function requestFancyboxCss() {
        link = document.createElement( 'link' ); 
        link.setAttribute( 'href', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css' );
        link.setAttribute( 'rel', 'stylesheet' );
        link.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body' [0])).appendChild(link);
        requestedFancyBoxCss = true;
    } 

    function checkDependancies() {
        if (typeof $ === 'undefined' || typeof $.fancybox === 'undefined' || !requestedFancyBoxCss) {

            if(!requestedJQuery && typeof $ === 'undefined') {
                requestJQuery();
            }

            if(!requestedFancyBoxJs && (typeof $ === 'undefined' || typeof $.fancybox === 'undefined')) {
                requestFancyboxJs();
            }

            if(!requestedFancyBoxCss) {
                requestFancyboxCss();
            }           

            setTimeout(function () {
                checkDependancies();
            }, 1);

        } else {
            displayFancyBox();
        }
    }


    function displayFancyBox() {
        var link = $('<a>');
        link.css('display', 'none');
        link.attr('href', 'http://example.org/another_page');
        link.addClass('fancybox fancybox.iframe');
        link.fancybox();
        link.trigger('click');
    }

    checkDependancies();

})()
```

Within the popup window, I have a button to close this popup. Here is Javascript for that:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
        parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
});
```

I got the error in Firefox when clicking the button:

```
Permission denied to access property 'jQuery'
```

Any idea about how to fix this?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
http://othersite.com/test.html
```

...loads your application from

```
http://example.org/showPopup.js
```

...then `othersite.com/test.html` is actually opening an `iframe` with `http://example.org/another_page` inside of it.

If the assumption above is correct, then

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()
```

...is trying to access `othersite.com/test.html` from within `http://example.org/another_page`, which might be violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), hence the error.

The only possible solution I see is that

```
http://othersite.com/test.html
```

...should allow access to your domain by setting an

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

... HTTP header ([learn more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)), which seems unlikely.